# Moment.js conversion of RFC2822 date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date as '04 FEB 1994' which I'm trying to convert into a date object for comparison.

I've tried a whole bunch of variations, the current one is...

```
var trydate = moment(licDob, "DD-MMM-YYYY");
var momentObj = moment(trydate);
var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

where licDob is 04 FEB 1994.  momentObj is coming back as 853506000000 which makes momentString 1997-01-18.

Guidance much appreciated.

Comment: try `DD MMM YYY`

Comment: Tried that thank @roottraveller, thought maybe the dashes would help since the moment docs say that non alphanumeric characters are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

use

`var newTry = moment(licDob,'DD MMM YYYY').toDate()`

considering you want to convert it to Date()

Answer (score 0):

You were close the the right solution. You have to use the `moment` constructor with 2 parameters. The 1st parameter is your string date and the 2nd is the format.

In your case the correct format is [`DD MMM YYYY`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```js
const stringDate = "04 FEB 1994";

const momentDate = moment(stringDate, "DD MMM YYYY");

console.log("Formatted:", momentDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
console.log("EPOCH:", momentDate.valueOf())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the assistance @Weedoze, but I'm not seeing the difference (aside from spaces in the date format rather than dashes which are ignored.  I'm giving the date and the format in var trydate

Comment: Indeed it gives the same results with or without the dashes. Then what is wrong with my solution ? It provides you the correct moment object, isn't it ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution @weedoze and it's appreciated but it's basically the same as what I had.  Problem turned out to be versioning of moment.js - I upgraded it and the problem was solved.  Thanks anyway.